# How can I repeat a value from one column according to a value from another column?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have data like below - one column with a value, the second with a count:

```
Name   Count
-----  -----
John    2
Smith   3
```

I want an output like below - each row consisting of the value in the first column repeated *n* times, where *n* is the value of the second column:

```
John,John
Smith,Smith,Smith
```

Is there a built-in Oracle function or SQL query that could be used to achieve this? If PL/SQL is required, that would also be helpful.

Comment: @bluefeet, I'm surprised by the "too broad" label on this one.  Perhaps OP needs to post code that he's attempted, but I dont see this as too many possible answers.

Comment: @paqogomez considering they are asking for suggestions on how to build this, yes I think there could be many possible answers.

Comment: @user3734923 To improve this post, it would be helpful to show what you've already tried and how its failed.  SO isnt a "Do this for me" site.  Post your attempts and i'm sure this question will be reopened.

Comment: Actually I am not able to come up with any idea. Hence reached to this forum.

Comment: PL/SQL is pretty easy, just write a function accepting the string and the count as input, and form the required string iterating n times. But beware the length of the returned only should be no longer than 4000.

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me that [RPAD](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/rpad.php) can do it

This is NOT TESTED as I don't have an Oracle db to hand

```
RPAD("", (LENGTH(name)+1)*count -1, name||',')
```

(`rpad` a blank string with `count` copies of the string, by requiring the result to be `(length(name)+1)*count` -1 long. The -1 is to remove the trailing comma )

Hat tip to OracleUser for the appending-the comma bit.

Comment: rpad(name||',',length(name)*count+(count-1),name||','). This should work.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not familiar with oracle, but if you know how to use recursion in oracle then you might be able to convert my T-SQL code to what works for you...

Step 1. Create test table containing your sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE #t ([Name] VARCHAR(20), [Count] INT);
INSERT INTO #t VALUES('John',2)
INSERT INTO #t VALUES('Smith',3)

SELECT * FROM #t
```

This gives the following output:

```
Name                 Count
-------------------- -----------
John                 2
Smith                3
```

Step 2. Recursive Query to get desired output:

```
DECLARE @Separator VARCHAR(3); SET @Separator = ','
;WITH myCTE AS (
    SELECT 1 AS [Count], [Name], [Count] AS RequiredCount, [Name] AS Result FROM #t
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [Count] + 1, [Name], RequiredCount, CAST(Result + @Separator + [Name] AS VARCHAR(20)) FROM myCTE WHERE RequiredCount > [Count]
)
SELECT [Count], [Name], Result FROM myCTE WHERE [Count] = RequiredCount
```

This gives the following output:

```
Count       Name                 Result
----------- -------------------- --------------------
3           Smith                Smith,Smith,Smith
2           John                 John,John
```

If this doesn't make sense to you, post a comment... I'll try and explain. I'm sure someone familiar with PL/SQL can help you convert this to meet your needs.

All the best!